# Model validation being bypassed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a Comment model, in which I validate the presence of all fields. However, I used AJAX to submit and display a comment. Now, the validation is no more working and users can submit empty comments. How do I enforce validation?

Comment: Would you edit your answer to include the validation methods as defined in your model? also, include in your controller the line of code that calls .sav

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use active record validation with AJAX, you need to implement it through rjs.

Have a look at these examples

http://railscasts.com/episodes/43-ajax-with-rjs

http://minimalbugs.com/questions/how-to-make-ajax-with-rjs

http://www.rubyinside.com/16-rjs-resources-and-tutorials-for-rails-programmers-5.html